# How do I rectify an error while installing Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence

While trying to install Tableau, I'm getting the following error:

```
0x80070666 Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue.
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove it, like stated in the error message?

Comment: I tried but there is no such file

Comment: Via System Settings Add/Remove Programs. Deinstall it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Computer -> Uninstall or change a program, find Tableau and remove it
2. Go to the drive where you install the Tableau and delete the folder (If you are using Windows try the following path: C:\Program Files\Tableau or C:/Program Files (x86)/Tableau). This is because even if you removed the program, there are still some remaining files stay in the Tableau folder.

Hope that helps!